# Magento : How to get simple products details on configurable product page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, phtml

On configurable product page, how do I get the information or attributes assigned to current product based on the Simple product which I associated to configurable product.

So if I had a Tile with 3 Finishes on there, Natural, Gloss, Textured and all these finishes have a different description and attributes values assigned to them how would i bring it up based on a finish being selected.

I'm using Magento 1.9 so "Simple Configurable Products" plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Ended up fixing this issue by using an extension known as

[Amasty Colour Swatches Pro](https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html?gclid=Cj0KEQiA5bvEBRCM6vypnc7QgMkBEiQAUZftQKr2007bXTIA4pwfn0yivJnB2JUzUFo-tY8Z9Ct_7J8aAo9l8P8HAQ)

The way we did it was by using the 'Additional Tabs' Tab in the Products page to show each individual attribute of a products and then combined with the colour swatch extension allows the data to change based on the filter selection.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share the code changes you've made to achieve this implementation? I've got these requirements and using the Amasty Color swatches pro extension.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can get this via this github URL here:https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Comment: Thanks! Nits. But I don't want to use the SCP extension. I just want to show one attribute data based on the configurable product options selection. I'm already using the Amasty color swatches pro extension which is doing the same thing. I just want to add my custom attribute in tabs for simple products.